# Paperclip error in rails3 on passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, paperclip

Rails3 on passenger. I have imagemagick installed and working correctly however I receive the following error when trying to add an image via paperclip. This works fine on in development, but not in production on passenger.

```
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::PaperclipError: There was an error processing the thumbnail for stream,11629,0>
    [paperclip] /usr/bin/identify '-format' '%wx%h' '/tmp/stream,11629,0.jpg[0]'
    [paperclip] /usr/bin/convert '/tmp/stream,11629,0.jpg[0]' '-resize' '100x100>' '/tmp/stream,11629,0,11629,1'
```

I created a paperclip.rb file in config/initializers and added

```
Paperclip.options[:swallow_stderr] = false
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin/"
```

but it hasn't fixed it for me.
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using Nginx or Apache? What is the size of your uploads?

Comment: apache, small files under 0.5mb, I tried different types, jpeg and png.

Comment: Have you tried to copy that `convert` command from the log and execute it manually to check if it works?

Comment: convert and identify both work when manually called on the server

Comment: And what's the result with large files? I ask, because larger files are sometimes handled differently - with a TempFile being created, whereas smaller files are passed as an IOStream for processing.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if rmagick is installed...

Run these commands

```
irb -rubygems -r RMagick
```

And then once inside of irb:

```
puts Magick::Long_version
```

You should get output like:

> This is RMagick 2.13.1 ($Date:
>   2009/12/20 02:33:33 $) Copyright (C)
>   2009 by Timothy P. Hunter Built with
>   ImageMagick 6.5.9-3 2010-02-19 Q16
>   http://www.imagemagick.org Built for
>   ruby 1.8.7 Web page:
>   http://rmagick.rubyforge.org Email:
>   rmagick@rubyforge.org
>   => nil

If you don't, then I think rmagick is not installed

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't solve the issue. Paperclip doesn't actually use RMagick. Paperclip shells out to ImageMagick. To check ImageMagick is correctly installed: `identify -version` or `convert -version`.

Comment: RMagick is installed.This is RMagick 2.13.1 ($Date: 2009/12/20 02:33:33 $) Copyright (C) 2009 by Timothy P. Hunter
Built with ImageMagick 6.5.7-8 2009-11-26 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Built for ruby 1.8.7
Web page: http://rmagick.rubyforge.org
Email: rmagick@rubyforge.org
=> nil

Comment: convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.5.7-8 2009-11-26 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2009 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP

Comment: @myabc - "RMagick is an interface between the Ruby programming language and ImageMagick/ GraphicsMagick."

Comment: It is indeed. RMagick is used by many other libraries, but not by Paperclip. Paperclip prefers instead to shell out to ImageMagick CLI tools.

Answer (score 0):

I have got a similar error ("processing the thumbnail for stream") if I try to create [rounded corners with Paper clip](http://loo.no/2009/08/09/rounded-corners-with-paperclip) ..

```
Command :: convert '/tmp/stream20120109-15817-1lju7p6-0.jpg[0]' -resize "918x" 
    [.. complicated options here..] 
    '/tmp/stream20120109-15817-1lju7p6-020120109-15817-17dl83e-0.png'
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::PaperclipError: 
There was an error processing the thumbnail for stream20120109-15817-1lju7p6-0>
```

How does your options for `has_attached_file` look like? Maybe a problem with ImageMagick parameters. In my case I wrote a plus sign instead of a minus - you had to use `-alpha off` instead of `+alpha off` - then error vanishes. Sometimes a single sign (- instead of + or vice versa) makes the difference.